# SQL: How to understand reason for needing to join on 2 columns for 3 tables

Tags: sql

I am told that the correct way to join these 3 tables, is to join on 2 columns, as demonstrated below:

```
SELECT c.code, name, region, e.year, fertility_rate, unemployment_rate  
FROM countries AS c  
INNER JOIN populations AS p 
ON c.code = p.country_code  
INNER JOIN economies AS e  
ON p.country_code = e.code AND p.year = e.year
```

My question relates to the error that occurs when I do it this way, without the "AND p.year = e.year" on the second inner join:

```
SELECT c.code, name, region, e.year, fertility_rate, unemployment_rate  
FROM countries AS c  
INNER JOIN populations AS p 
ON c.code = p.country_code  
INNER JOIN economies AS e  
ON p.country_code = e.code
```

The result is:

| Code | Country | Region | Year | Fertility Rate | unemployment rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | Afghanistan | Southern and Central Asia | 2015 | 5.746 | null |
| AFG | Afghanistan | Southern and Central Asia | 2010 | 5.746 | null |
| AFG | Afghanistan | Southern and Central Asia | 2015 | 4.653 | null |
| AFG | Afghanistan | Southern and Central Asia | 2010 | 4.653 | null |

My question is this: Why am I getting repeats of the years 2010 and 2015 with the 2 different values for fertility rate? The tutorial says "The trouble with doing your last join on c.code = e.code and not also including year is that e.g. the 2010 value for fertility_rate is also paired with the 2015 value for unemployment_rate."

I don't understand the explanation and therefore I don't understand conceptually what is going wrong here...

Can someone walk me through the steps SQL is taking?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Conceptually you are not specific enough. Your join expression does not match one row to one row. It matches many rows to many rows. SQL is not going to automatically decide which single row you mean so it returns all combinations of them. What do you think this expression should return?